# Как исправить ошибку аутентификации при отправки email в .Net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На фото мой код, который я почти содрал с этой статьи (https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.1.php). При вызове метода происходит ошибка аутентификации, но почта и пароль были внимательно проверены, при вводе я не ошибся. В комментах статьи сказано поменять настройки в аккаунте гугла, ssl(true/false) я это сделал, но безуспешно. Кто знает чем проблема? Так же в аккаунте гугла появились сообщения "Попытка входа заблокирована".

Comment: При отправке на яндекс похожие проблемы(

Comment: Попробуйте указать `client.Connect("smtp.google.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);` - 587 порт - это TLS подключение.
Либо указать 465 порт и ssl в true

Comment: Не, та же ошибка(

Comment: А для чего Вам `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` и `AuthenticationMechanism` ? Это принципиально их использовать? Буквально на днях настраивал свой сайт на Yandex почту, код примерно [следующий](http://i.imgur.com/IWmhUYF.png). Соединение идет по 465 порту и без всяких излишеств. На gmail должно все примерно так же быть. Так же еще раз стоит проверить свой логин и пароль, логин должен быть полный (login@gmail.com)

Comment: Я не знаю зачем они, это от безнадежности начал комбинировать все что то нашел в коментах. Похоже что в моем случае их присутствие\отсутствие не повлияло на результат. Написал как у тебя(полностью так же) за исключением почты и пароля, но нет, на google та же ошибка, на яндекс - "соед. не установлено тк. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение". Логин и пароль я копировал прямо из кода и смог зайти на почту - все написано правильно и полностью. Буду использовать другие решения или сторонние сервисы в таком случае( Даже нет идей в чем может быть проблема.